# Assert 2 strings are in alpha order

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

I am currently writing . a test to compare leaderboards entries in a betting table, Firstly i have to compare the result picks or the player (which is working) and then i have to compare each players points (which is working) but if both of these attributes are the same i have to assert the player higher on the table is higher alphabetically. I have created the variables username_player and previous_user to do this but cant figure out how to do it, Im trying to put it in the else if section (which i think is correct). There doesn't seem to be an assert option to do this?

```
public void test_player_leaderboard_entry() {



    int size = playerRows.size();
    Integer previous_total = 0;
    Integer previous_points = 0;
    String previous_user = null;


    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        //Position
        String position_first_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-position-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Points
        String points_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-points-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Username
        String username_player = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-qa-player-value='" + i + "']")).getText();
        //Row Number
        Integer row = i + 1;
        Integer point_player = Integer.parseInt(points_player);
        Integer total_of_won_and_looking_good = 0;



        //PICKS
        for (int pick_number = 1; pick_number < 5; pick_number++) {
            String pick_status = Drivers.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/main/section[2]/section/div/ol/a[" + row + "]/li/div[3]/div[" + pick_number + "]/div")).getAttribute("data-qa-pick-state");
            //System.out.println(pick_status);
            if (Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 2 || Integer.parseInt(pick_status) == 1) {
                total_of_won_and_looking_good = total_of_won_and_looking_good + 1;
            }




        } if(previous_total.equals(total_of_won_and_looking_good)) {

            Assert.assertTrue(previous_points > point_player);
            System.out.println("Picks are the same, points are higher ");

        } else if (previous_total.equals(total_of_won_and_looking_good)&& previous_points.equals(point_player)) {

            Assert.assertTrue(previous_user.compareTo(username_player) < 0);



        }
        previous_total = total_of_won_and_looking_good;
        previous_points = point_player;

        previous_user = username_player;


        System.out.println("On row number " + row + " we find " + username_player + " in position " + position_first_player + " with " + total_of_won_and_looking_good + " correct picks and " + points_player + " points!");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the compareTo method.

Try using an assertion for `previous_user.compareTo(username_player) <0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use compareTo method on Strings which compares them lexicographically. So you can do something like

`Assert.assertTrue(previous_user.compareTo(username_player) < 0)`

Edit:
Maybe you can try it like this but I am not entirely sure that is what you want:

```
        if(previous_total.equals(total_of_won_and_looking_good)) {

            Assert.assertTrue(previous_points > point_player);
            System.out.println("Picks are the same, points are higher ");

        } else if (previous_points.equals(point_player)) {

            Assert.assertTrue(previous_user.compareTo(username_player) < 0);

        }
```

Comment: Where should i add this? Ive tried to put it in the else if part of the code but the if part seems to over write it some how? Im trying to assert if the points and picks are the same then assert eh strings are in alpha, im thinking its in the wrong place? Im really bad with if statements, ive changed the code in my question to reflect this